# Get first 3 letters of a string from a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to get extract first 3 letters from a string in dataframe column and store them in a new column.

Extract the first three letters/numbers from the column 'A' and store it in the column 'C'

DATA:

```
   A        B      
12525    1FWE23   
14654    22354    
24798    32684     
38945    45368     
46456    46485     
AD545    45346     
A5D66    58446
```

EXPECTED :

```
   A        B      C
12525    1FWE23   125       
14654    22354    146
24798    32684    247
38945    45368    389
46456    46485    464
AD545    45346    AD5
A5D66    58446    A5D
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we re-create the dataframe from the example you provided:

```
from io import StringIO

s = """
   A        B      
12525    1FWE23   
14654    22354    
24798    32684     
38945    45368     
46456    46485     
AD545    45346     
A5D66    58446      
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), sep="\s+", engine='python')
```

Next, create a new column `C` by using [string accessor methods](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/series.html#api-series-str):

```
df['C'] = df['A'].str.slice(0, 3)

# Equivalently:
# df['C'] = df['A'].str[:3]
```

Verifying that the result is as desired via `print(df)`:

```
       A       B    C
0  12525  1FWE23  125
1  14654   22354  146
2  24798   32684  247
3  38945   45368  389
4  46456   46485  464
5  AD545   45346  AD5
6  A5D66   58446  A5D
```

Comment: I tried Slice but it didn't worked. But this one "df['A'].str[:3]" worked correctly.  Thank you @BigBen and Arthur

Comment: @Pravin did you access the `slice` function via the string accessor method? There was a typo in my original post (now fixed), but this should work: `df['C'] = df['A'].str.slice(0, 3)`. If it works, feel free to accept the answer.

Comment: the code works correctly and the answer is accepted